# C# Possible unintended reference comparison

Tags: c#, reference, comparison

When i try to check `Session["userId"] != null` why i get this message `Possible unintended reference comparrison; to get value comparrison; cast left hand side to string` Any suggestion....

Comment: Where and how do you get that message? What version of the compiler are you using? When I compile the code in VS 2008 I don't get any warning.

Comment: Maybe the code has been sanitized a little?

Comment: Esp. as the error message has a typo :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Session[key]` returns an **object**, not a string - you should be casting it to string rather than relying on implicit casting or ToString() functionality.

Answer (score 1):

```
        if(Session["userId"]!=null)
        {

        }
```

works just fine for me

Answer (score 0):

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) {
        return "is null or empty";
}
    else{

        return String.Format("(\"{0}\") is not null or empty", s);
}
```

/* true if the value parameter is null or an empty string (""); otherwise, false. */